# Android: Multiple Option Menus in one Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

I have an `Activity` containing a `ViewFlipper` and would like to show a different option menu for each view in that `ViewFlipper`. That is, the type of menu displayed when the menu button is pressed would depend on the type of the current view.

However, `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called only once (when showing the option menu for the first time), so creating the different menus can't be implemented there.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First read about [onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)

Each time the user presses the <kbd>Menu</kbd> on their Android device while inside one of your activities, the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method is called.  The first time the menu is shown (i.e. *only once*), the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method is called.

Basically, the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method is where you should make any changes such as enabling/disabling certain menu items, or changing the menu item text depending on the circumstances.

So do this (Don't use `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` )

```
//Dynamically create context Menu
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear(); //Clear view of previous menu
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        if(condition_true)
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_one, menu);
        else
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_two, menu);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```