# How to add an extra menu to android toolbar in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, menu

The question is clear! I need to add another menu beside of the main menu in toolbar. I have created the status.xml menu file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/online"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/busy"
        android:orderInCategory="20"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/invisible"
        android:orderInCategory="30"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

and added a clickable TextView to toolbar like this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    ... />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Now I need to add it separately to the toolbar, but in code below:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.status, menu)
        return true
    }
```

It add all of items to main menu. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You want "add another menu beside of the main menu in toolbar", the result is "It add all of items to main menu", so what is the problem?

Comment: I mean I need two menus, main and status

Answer (score 0):

If this menus have to be separate that appear depending on some kind of condition you can use onPrepareOptionsMenu.
Check this question and developer guide on menus
[Android: Multiple Option Menus in one Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011210/android-multiple-option-menus-in-one-activity)
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus

Comment: Thank you for your help. Although this is not what I want, but it was helpful to do this in another way. What I need is two separate menus in a toolbar. In the other words, I have normal menu in the toolbar, and I have a TextView that is clickable, next to the normal menu button. by each tap on it, another menu will open like the normal menu, but with different contents.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to the `<item>` you to display as seperate item in status bar :

`<item> app:showAsAction="always" </item>`